# Probability of red ball i before any black ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Assume we have $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls in a box and we remove one ball at a time without replacement. Red balls are labeled from $1$ to $r$. We want to calculate the probability a particular ball $i$ is chosen before any black ball is chosen.

I know how to solve the problem using conditioning on the first ball taken, and also by counting the number of permutations of b+1 objects (1 corresponds to the red ball) where the red ball is before any black ball. In both cases we find that:

Prob(red ball i is chosen before any black ball)=$\frac{1}{b+1}$

Can we solve the above problem by counting the permutations of all the $r+b$ objects where red ball $i$ is before any black balls in order to find the probability of interest?

I have tried the above but I find a dependence on $r$, the number of red balls which does seem to agree with the $\frac{1}{b+1}$ result we took above.

In other words, the question can become: do we care at all about the rest of the red balls (except red ball i) or not? If we count them, our sample space changes.

Comment: Taking into account the irrelevant balls should just multiply the numerator and the denominator by the same factor, so the answer to your question is "Yes, we can". If you write how you derived the result that depends on $r$, someone might be able to point out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work it out (the long way) by counting how many red balls show up before the red ball labeled $i$. Say there are $k$ red balls before the red ball $i$, then we choose which $k$ out of the remaining $r-1$ red balls in $\binom{r-1}{k}$ ways, arrange the $k$ balls in $k!$ ways, and arrange the balls after the red ball labeled $i$ in $(r+b - k - 1)!$ ways.

Therefore, the number of ways of arranging them is $\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom{r-1}{k}k!(r+b-k-1)!$

This simplifies to $(r-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \frac{(r+b-k-1)!}{(r-k-1)!} = b!(r-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{r+b-k-1}{b}$

Relabeling the sum, gives $b!(r-1)! \sum_{i=b}^{r+b-1} \binom{i}{b}$, where the sum is a well known identity solving to $\binom{r+b}{b+1}$. Therefore, there are $b!(r-1)!\binom{r+b}{b+1} = \frac{(r+b)!}{b+1}$ ways for the red ball labeled $i$ to appear before any black ball. Since there are $(r+b)!$ arrangements total, the probability is $\frac{1}{b+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about ball $i$ and the black balls, you can ignore all the rest.  Imagine painting them all green-what does that change here?  You certainly could solve it by counting all permutations of the $r+b$ objects and finding how many have ball $i$ before any black balls, but that is a lot more work than what you already did.  You could say there are $(b+r-1)!$ permutations where ball $i$ is first, and it precedes all the black balls in all of them.  There are $(b+r-1)!$ where ball $i$ is second and it preceeds all the black balls in $\frac {r-1}{b+r-1}$ of them, and so on.